# How to make a sitemap using zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, sitemap

I want to create a sitemap for a website that is coded in zf1 but I don't know anything about this.

I've read on google that I need a controller, a view and routes for it but what I found is for zf2 and doesn't works.

Did someone makes this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Zend_Navigation` class and `navigation sitemap` view helper inside a Controller Action, as follows:

```
public function sitemapAction()
{
  $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
  $items = array(
    array(
      'title' => 'Title 1',
      'label' => 'Label 1',
      'uri' => 'https://www.example.com/page1',
      'order' => 1,
      'type' => 'uri',
      'changefreq' => 'weekly',
    ),
    array(
      'title' => 'Title 2',
      'label' => 'Label 2',
      'uri' => 'https://www.example.com/page2',
      'order' => 2,
      'type' => 'uri',
      'changefreq' => 'weekly',
    )
  );
  $nav = new Zend_Navigation($items);
  $sitemapOutput = $this->view->navigation($nav)->sitemap();

  $this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')->setBody($sitemapOutput);
}
```